Gromov hyperbolicity is a quasi-isometric invariant for roughly geodesic metric spaces
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. We say a continuous path $\gamma:[a,b]\to X$ is a rough geodesic if there exists $C>0$ such that for any $x,y\in [a,b]$, $|x-y|-C\leq d(\gamma(x),\gamma(y))\leq |x-y|+C$. We say $(X,d)$ is roughly geodesic if any two points in $X$ can be connected by a rough geodesic. We say $(X,d)$ is Gromov hyperbolic if there exists a $\delta\geq 0$ such that for any four points $x,y,z,w\in X$, $$(x,y)_w\geq \min\{(x,z)_w, (y,z)_w\}-\delta.$$
We know that Gromov hyperbolicity is a quasi-isometric invariant for geodesic metric spaces, but NOT quasi-isometric invariant for quasi-geodesic metric spaces, for example see here. I recently read a paper (p.g. 954) saying Gromov hyperbolicity is a quasi-isometric invariant for roughly geodesic space but couldn't figure the reasons. The only thing I know is: given a quasi-isometry $f:X\to Y$ from a hyperbolic geodesic space $X$ to a roughly geodesic space $Y$, then $Y$ is hyperbolic (using quasi-rulers).
I'd appreciate if someone could help or know any references!

I suggest following the reference found at that link, to the paper of Bonk and Schramm.
